# Repeat command execution attempts until status is not specific, preserve data

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, stdout, exit-status

I have a case where a first few command execution attempts after daemon restart are returning 2 (followed by stderr messages),
than everything works correctly.

In order to bypass this bug I've come to an idea that I should utilize `while/do/done/until` functionality with some `sleep`, but the fun part is that I should have all the data I'd get by the regular execution way:

```
...
RESULT=$(command param1 param2 2>&1)
SIG=$?
...
```

So is there a way to execute `command param1 param2` repeatedly until exit status is NOT 2 (any given value) and to have STDOUT+STDERR in a variable `RESULT` and exit status in variable `SIG`, as presented?

Answer (score 2):

```
outfile=$(mktemp)

while ! command param1 param2 >"$outfile" 2>&1; do
    [ "$?" -ne 2 ] && break
    sleep 10
done

result=$(<"$outfile")
rm "$outfile"
```

This would run the command over and over again (with a 10 second delay in-between each time), until it succeeds or at least does not return a `2` as exit status.

The output of the command is written to a temporary file which, after the loop, is read into a variable and deleted.  The reading into a variable bit requires `bash`, the way I've written it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
until [ "$SIG" != "2" ]; do
   command param1 param2
   SIG=$?
done
```

This will run the command every time until it returns a number different from 2.